# A word that describes the polite phrases we use to begin our letters

Tags: word-choice, phrasing

How can we refer to the polite phrase used at the beginning of a letter (email in my specific context)?

For example, we may start our letter:

> Dear Bob, I hope that you're well and had a nice weekend.

If we want to make reference to the line

> I hope that you're well and had a nice weekend

in such a way that we could say:

> I often wonder how to begin a letter of bad news, but my
>   [interjection] stands genuine non the less

The term "interjection" doesn't seem like a good fit here. Is there a word that describes the polite phrases we often use to begin our letters?

Comment: If I understand the question well, these aren't phrases, they are sentences. I am not aware of a specific term, but they look like **model sentences** to me.

Comment: Perhaps "opening" or "opening line" or "opening sentence"?

Comment: Platitude? Filler?

Comment: Platitude, that sounds like the right kind of word.

Comment: In grade school, we learned this is the 'salutation'. I've never heard it described otherwise.

Comment: In the case of bad news, there's perhaps no easy way to sugar-coat things. I wouldn't try to reinforce my good intention at the start, but I would say I'm sorry to have to be the bearer of bad news.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Either '[greeting](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/greeting)' or '[salutation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/salutation)' would fit.

From the online dictionary, meaning 3 is appropriate:

> sal·u·ta·tion  (sly-tshn) n.
>
> 1. a. A polite expression of greeting or goodwill. b. salutations Greetings indicating respect and affection; regards.
> 2. A gesture of greeting, such as a bow or kiss.
> 3. A word or phrase of greeting used to begin a letter or message.

Comment: Don't these refer to expressions like *"Dear X"* or *"Best wishes"*? OP is asking about full sentences after the greeting.

Comment: The salutation can cover all of this, eg. "Dear Irene, I hope this comment finds you in rude health."

Answer (score 11):

**[pleasantries](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pleasantries)**
plural of pleas·ant·ry (Noun)

A polite social utterance; a civility: *exchanged pleasantries before getting down to business.*

Answer (score 6):

Upon reading the question, my mind immediatly jumped to 'preamble'.

> **pre·am·ble**
>   **/ˈprēˌambəl/**
>
> A preliminary or preparatory statement;
>   an introduction. The introductory part of a statute or deed, stating
>   its purpose, aims, and justification. Synonyms preface - introduction
>   - proem - foreword - prelude

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a word that describes this kind of remark (sentence) when it is made in a written context such as a letter. On the other hand, the term *phatic* is used to describe similar sorts of remarks when they are spoken. "How are you?" is frequently used as a phatic utterance; consider, for example, the telephone sales-person who greets you when you answer the phone with "Hello Ms Smith, How are you today?" The correct (social) response is "Fine, thank you", not a truthful answer that describes your state of well-being. The reason is that the question is *phatic*; that is (to quote the OED), "it serves to establish or maintain social relationships rather than to impart information, communicate ideas".

Comment: You took the words right out of my mouth.  Phatic communication (sometimes called phatic communion) is a normal part of everyday life.  It's small talk.  It's utterances that are taken for granted because they are so common and so useful in greasing the wheels of interpersonal communication.  We all use'em:  in greetings, in leave-takings ("Well, I'd better be going"), in escaping a boring person ("Would you excuse me?"), and so on.  Socially acceptable lies; unconscious utterances; "weather talk"--they are all instances of phatic communion.